# plot gridded map with lat-lon and fill values in csv file in Python

Tags: pandas, csv, matplotlib-basemap, geopandas

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLvL8.png)I have a `.csv` file contains a few columns: `lon, lat, var1, var2 ...`

```
df = pd.read_csv('D:/file.csv')
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df)
Lon = df['lon']
Lat = df['lat']
Slope = df['slope']
```

**Edit**: How can I plot my data in the above table (*lon, lat, slope*) on a global gridded map with lon `(-179.5 degree to 179.5 degree), lat (-89.5 to 89.5 degree)` and spatial resolution of 1 degree.

[image: dataframe image]
[[image]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import pandas as pd
import random

latz = np.linspace(-89.5, 89.5, 180)
lonz = np.linspace(-0.5, 359.5, 361)
x, y = np.meshgrid(lonz, latz)

rand_list = [random.randrange(1, 5, 1) for i in range(64980)]

# you probably need to sort your df by lat/long and
# you'll want to replace rand_list with:
#z = np.array_split(df['slope'].values.tolist(), 180)

z = np.array_split(rand_list, 180)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[16, 16])
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.set_extent([-179.5, 180, -89.5, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND, zorder=1, facecolor='0.25')
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN, zorder=4)

ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), zorder=3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort and sorry for not clarified question. The post has been edited. Actually, I need to plot my data, over a global map like yours.

Comment: I edited my response to plot some sample data on the map as well. Also MPL Basemap (per your tag) is deprecated in favor of the Cartopy project.

Comment: Thanks again for your time and effort. Your code rotate the data and mirror them. However, I meant I need to create a raster dataset with 1-degree spatial resolution, those grid points that I have the data should be filled with `slope` values  (as a pixel with 1-degree resolution, not scatter-point), and the others defined as `NaN`. For example I can later use `pcolormesh` to plot the data, or save the data in netcdf format.  I have added an image as an example.

Comment: OK, I edited my answer to what I think you want. You'll need to replace my made up data with your df['slope'] column. See comment in code.